# Java Connecting 2 Computers with Server-Client System

Tags: java, sockets, networking, client-server, broadcasting

I would like to ask a question about server-client applications using a `ServerSocket` in Java. It is going to be a long question, but if somebody can help me in this big homework of mine, I would really appreciate it. :)

Some time ago, I wrote a program using Netbeans which connects the 2 or more JFrame clients to the server JFrame, and allows all these windows to communicate with each other by sending text to the server. This is a brief example of how it works.

I run the server application, server opens. I run the client application, more than once, lets just say 3 and `A`, `B`, `C` are these different frames which run totally independent from each other.
For example the user at `C` frame sends a text to talk with other frames. Text goes from `C` To `Server`, then `Server` sends the same text to `A`, `B` and `C`; and this message is visible from the users' frames.

THE QUESTION IS, I am kinda rookie in this Networking and I did this in Only ONE Computer. But as expected, I must be able to do this in several computers. But I don't know how to do it.

- Will it work when I write the client IPs?
- Do i have to change some settings at my computers to make this happen?

Any help is really appreciated, thank you all. :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the computers are on the same local area network, and you connect to the appropriate IP for the server, it should all work fine.